# Array of values only gives last one

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
 array(4) { [109]=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "109" ["name"]=> string(29) "unsplash_52cd96f512830_1.jpeg" ["path"]=> string(113) "/Users/framecero/Framecero_Clientes/MIMO/MAMP/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_52cd96f512830_1.jpeg" ["url"]=> string(97) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_52cd96f512830_1-150x150.jpeg" ["width"]=> int(150) ["height"]=> int(150) ["full_url"]=> string(89) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_52cd96f512830_1.jpeg" ["title"]=> string(24) "unsplash_52cd96f512830_1" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["alt"]=> string(0) "" } [113]=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "113" ["name"]=> string(29) "unsplash_52d65d1ebeeb2_1.jpeg" ["path"]=> string(113) "/Users/framecero/Framecero_Clientes/MIMO/MAMP/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_52d65d1ebeeb2_1.jpeg" ["url"]=> string(97) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_52d65d1ebeeb2_1-150x150.jpeg" ["width"]=> int(150) ["height"]=> int(150) ["full_url"]=> string(89) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_52d65d1ebeeb2_1.jpeg" ["title"]=> string(24) "unsplash_52d65d1ebeeb2_1" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["alt"]=> string(0) "" } [132]=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "132" ["name"]=> string(29) "unsplash_523ae1f5502d6_1.jpeg" ["path"]=> string(113) "/Users/framecero/Framecero_Clientes/MIMO/MAMP/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_523ae1f5502d6_1.jpeg" ["url"]=> string(97) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_523ae1f5502d6_1-150x150.jpeg" ["width"]=> int(150) ["height"]=> int(150) ["full_url"]=> string(89) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/unsplash_523ae1f5502d6_1.jpeg" ["title"]=> string(24) "unsplash_523ae1f5502d6_1" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["alt"]=> string(0) "" } [163]=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "163" ["name"]=> string(12) "building.jpg" ["path"]=> string(96) "/Users/framecero/Framecero_Clientes/MIMO/MAMP/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/building.jpg" ["url"]=> string(80) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/building-150x150.jpg" ["width"]=> int(150) ["height"]=> int(150) ["full_url"]=> string(72) "http://localhost:8888/fashionist/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/building.jpg" ["title"]=> string(8) "building" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["alt"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

I need to get the url in a foreach and i am using this code:

```
<?php global $post;$medias = rwmb_meta( 'mimo_imgadv', 'type=image_advanced' );?>
<?php  } else {$medias = '';}; ?>
<?php if ($medias !== ''){ ?>
<div  class="cn_wrapper flexslider" >
    <ul id="allimg_id<?php the_Id(); ?>" class="format_images slides">
        <?php foreach($medias as $media){

        // check if string ends with image extension
            if (preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.png|\.bmp)$/', $media['url'])) {
                echo '<li class="selector">';
                ?>
                <a class="mimo-link-overimage" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> " >
                         <div class="mimo-image-hover"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i></div> 

                <?php
                echo '<img src="' . $media['url']  . '" alt=""/>';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</li>';
            // check if there is youtube.com in string
            }           
        }       

        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it only gives me the last url.

Anyone knows what is happening with the code?

Comment: The only url I actually see there ends with `"jpeg"`, which wouldn't match your regex at all.

Comment: Hi, i finally solved it, the thing is that the code above is working :)

Comment: I also what you recommended with 'jpeg' but it was working without it ?¿?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit your regex to detect the file types you have in your array. You are looking for types .jpg, .png, and .bmp, but there is only one file in the array of those types. That's why you got only one result. The other three images are .jpeg. Here is the edited code to include the other files:

```
<?php foreach($medias as $media){
    // check if string ends with image extension
    if (preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp)$/', $media['url'])) {
        echo '<li class="selector">';
        //remaining code unchanged...
?>
```